# Return the last characters of a link in bash

Tags: awk

I have the following link from my local deployment:

https://localhost/internal-repo/test-tools/local-repo/docker-image-internal-1.2-dirty.tgz

I want to return only `1.2-dirty`, I started with:

```
less version.txt | awk 'NR==1 {print $1}'
```

but it returns the whole link.

Do you have any idea how I can proceed?

Comment: With only a single example, we can't see how to generalize this. Do you want to print everything after the penultimate dash, up to the last dot? Or everything after from the last number up to before the last dot? Or the last nine characters before the extension? Or something else? Anyway, we have a galaxy's worth of similar questions; please search before asking, at least so that you can articulate a well-defined problem statement. Awk has the `-F` option for declaring a different delimiter, so you can probably adapt your attempt with fairly small changes.

Comment: Also, probably use the `less`; this is [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) on steroids. Awk can read a file by itself; your command is equivalent to `awk 'NR==1 {print $1}' version.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181271/extract-version-using-regular-expressions-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can something like this:

```
awk -F'[-/]' '{gsub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", $NF); print $(NF-1) "-" $NF}'
```

`-F'[-/]'` sets the field separator to either '-' or '/'. This means that each part of the URL between '-' and '/' will be treated as a separate field.

`gsub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", $NF)` uses the gsub function in AWK, which stands for "global substitution". It searches for a pattern in the specified field ($NF, which refers to the last field), and replaces it with the given string (in this case, an empty string)

`print $(NF-1) "-" $NF` prints the second-to-last field ($(NF-1)) followed by a hyphen and then the last field ($NF). This concatenation gives you the desired version string

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cut` this is really easy to use. This will return the 7th and 8th part when cutting at `-` and then deletes the extionsion with the same method.

`... | cut -d"-" -f7,8 | cut -d"." -f1,2`

There are better ways to do it, but I find this easy to understand and alter.

Answer (score 0):

Using any sed:

```
$ echo 'https://localhost/internal-repo/test-tools/local-repo/docker-image-internal-1.2-dirty.tgz' |
sed 's/.*-\([^-]*-[^-.]*\).*/\1/'
1.2-dirty
```

That produces the output you expect from the 1 sample input line you provided but obviously, just like any other answer you get given that one line of sample input, I've no idea if it's an adequate general solution that'd work for whatever other input you expect.